# Why this database takes longer time than the same database with more rows?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a method that use the SELECT query and use the data containing

I only use the SELECT query for my app to fetch the data

The problem is that my new database is too slow for processing the method

I had an old DB file which i was using before i made my own one

It took  0.063548225 s on average to process with the old DB

And it took 4.202198266 s on average like 70 times longer process time than with the old one

I first thought it's because of the number of raws's difference between those DB files

So i tested again after deleting many rows in my new DB file

And weird thing is that it took time longer than the one with more rows like 5.903229880 s

my old DB created with these queries

```
CREATE TABLE korean_english (word TEXT, def BLOB)
CREATE INDEX idx_korean_english_word ON korean_english(word ASC)
```

and it contains 49,757 rows in the table
It took 0.063548225 s with this

and my new DB

```
CREATE TABLE korean_english ( word TEXT, def TEXT, num INTEGER )
```

and it contains 599,251 rows
It took 4.202198266 s with this

and my new reduced DB

```
DELETE FROM korean_english WHERE ROWID > 50000
```

so it contains 50,000 rows

I'm pretty sure it's about DB files because i just changed the DB file nothing else more

I really don't know why it takes time so much longer and even with less rows

Comment: I think you're confusing columns and rows...

Comment: Does your new table have an index like the old one does? If not that would explain the difference.

Comment: @Shawn Oh right I'm really sorry it's raws

Comment: @Shawn No, it doesn't have.

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. Create an index and try timing it again.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, i will try soon! But even if it was because of indexing why with less rows takes much time than with more rows?

Comment: It's better to look what is index : https://www.programmerinterview.com/database-sql/what-is-an-index/

Comment: @Volkan Albayrak thank you i will look right away